# Resize the cursor

Tags: css, angular, typescript, cursor, image-resizing

I'm building a drawing application (Like paint or Sketchpad) and I need to resize my cursor depending on of the line width of the pencil. The problem is, apparently, you can't resize your cursor. The solution that I found is to use a custom cursor (the normal cursor is changed for an image) and to resize the image. The thing is, I don't know if I need a function to do that or I can directly change the size of the image via SCSS (CSS).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
private setCursor(cursorType: DrawingCursor): void {
this.Canvas.setAttribute("style", "cursor:url(" + cursorType + "), auto;");}
```

The cursorType is the url of the custom cursor.

I'm doing this from an angular 8 project (in Typescript).

Thank you !

Comment: you can use class to update the cursor url once you've set the type of pencil (use a differet class and cursor for each pencil) It has to be done from your script , not scss,scss can only generates your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NgClass](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass) binding to implement it. This way the Angular binding takes care of applying the CSS classes so you don't need to set styles manually.

To implement this solution first define the CSS classes for the canvas and the different cursor sizes. For example:

```
.myCanvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}

.brush18px {
  cursor: url('brush18px.png'), auto;
}

.brush24px {
  cursor: url('brush24px.png'), auto;
}

.brush36px {
  cursor: url('brush36px.png'), auto;
}
```

Then in the component you define a property that will provide the classes for the canvas and a property for the size of the brush. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @Input() cursorSize = '18';
  get canvasClasses() {
    return {
      myCanvas: true,
      brush18px: this.cursorSize === '18',
      brush24px: this.cursorSize === '24',
      brush36px: this.cursorSize === '36',
    };
  };
}
```

The `canvasClasses` property must return an object that specifies for each CSS class name if it is applied or not by setting the value to true or false. I use a getter property here so the values update automatically when the size changes.

Now you can bind this in the template and the cursor will automatically update based on the `cursorSize` value.

Here is how the template looks like:

```
<canvas [ngClass]="canvasClasses"></canvas>
<br/>
<select [(ngModel)]="cursorSize">
  <option>18</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>36</option>
</select>
```

I have created also a working [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cursor?file=src/app/app.component.ts) so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! So about your solution, I've already thought about it. The thing is, I would choose this alternative if I can't do what I'm asking for. Having one picture that can be resized however I want (in width and in height) instead of having predefined size would be more "suitable" for my app.

Comment: I added another answer with a different solution that offers resize by hiding the cursor and using an image as a fake cursor check if this might be useful. I will leave this answer since it is also a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution based on the comment on the first answer. This is more of a workaround solution where you hide the actual cursor and move around an image instead so it looks like it is the cursor. This was inspired by the second answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248257/resizing-css-custom-mouse-cursor) about resizing a cursor image.

I implemented this solution in Angular using a directive that you add to the canvas element in the template. The directive takes as the main parameter the image to show as the cursor and  has an additional parameter for the size for the image. I recommend an SVG image that resizes well. Still it is possible to use also a standard image.

Here is the implementation of the Directive for an SVG image:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[svgCursor]'
})
export class SvgCursorDirective {
  private cursorSizeValue: number = 16;
  @Input('svgCursor') public svgImage: SVGSVGElement;
  @Input() public set cursorSize(cursorSize: number) {
    this.cursorSizeValue = cursorSize;
    this.updateCursorSize();
  }

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.cursor = 'none'; // hides the browser cursor
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    // makes image visible only when mous enters the element
    this.svgImage.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }

  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event']) onMouseMove(e: MouseEvent) {
    // draws the image at the mouse position
    this.svgImage.style.left = e.clientX.toString();
    this.svgImage.style.top = (e.clientY - this.cursorSizeValue).toString();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    // hides image when the mouse leaves the element
    this.svgImage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  private updateCursorSize() {
    if (this.svgImage != null) {
      this.svgImage.style.width = this.cursorSizeValue.toString();
      this.svgImage.style.height = this.cursorSizeValue.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have the directive you can use it in the following way inside a component template:

```
<svg #cursorImage class="cursor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M7 14c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3 0 1.31-1.16 2-2 2 .92 1.22 2.49 2 4 2 2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4 0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm13.71-9.37l-1.34-1.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L9 12.25 11.75 15l8.96-8.96c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41z"/></svg>
<canvas class="myCanvas" [svgCursor]="cursorImage" [cursorSize]="cursorSize"></canvas>
```

As you can see you need to add a template reference variable to the image so you can pass it as a parameter to the svgCursor directive.

Also important for this to work you need to set the correct CSS styles to the image to disable things that are not needed. It is also set to invisble so it becomes visible only when the mouse enters te canvas.

This are the styles I used:

```
.myCanvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I have created also a working [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-cursor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsvg-cursor.directive.ts) so you can see how this works.